# How do I make a background image transparent in CSS?

Tags: html, css

```
<style>
  header {
   text-align: center;
   background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/7L79iny.jpg');
   background-size: 100% 100%;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;  
  }
```

This is the code I'm using to add a background image to my header. How to I make the image semi-transparent without making the rest of the header transparent.

```
<header>
 <center><a href="http://imgur.com/EPd7PBU"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/EPd7PBU.jpg" height=350 title="source: imgur.com" /></a></center>
 <h1>Taylor's Blog</h1>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Blogs</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
 </ul>
</header>
```

Comment: in short: you can't. You can make the image itself transparent by converting it to a PNG and adding transparency, or you can have an actual image hidden behind the `<header>` that has a set `opacity`

Comment: Also `<center>` has been deprecated and should no longer be used.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the opacity of a background image with css, only the opacity of an element. However, there is a very easy work-around, that only requires css:

```css
header {
   text-align: center;
   position:relative;
  }
  header:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/7L79iny.jpg');
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;  
    opacity:0.5;
  }
```

```html
<header>
<a href="http://imgur.com/EPd7PBU"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/EPd7PBU.jpg" height=350 title="source: imgur.com" /></a>
 <h1>Taylor's Blog</h1>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Blogs</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
 </ul>
</header>
```

On another note, [`<center>` is depreciated](http://www.html-5.com/changes/deprecated/center-tag.html), and should not be used. In fact, in the case of the html you have, the link and image are already centered with `text-align:center;`, making the center tag useless.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to create an absolutely positioned div that is transparent and is layered under the content.

```
<style>
  header {
   position: relative;
  }
  header .background {
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   height:100;
   opacity: .5;
   background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/7L79iny.jpg');
   background-size: 100% 100%;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;  
  }
</style>
```

sadsad

```
<header>
 <div class="background"></div>
 <center><a href="http://imgur.com/EPd7PBU"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/EPd7PBU.jpg" height=350 title="source: imgur.com" /></a></center>
 <h1>Taylor's Blog</h1>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Blogs</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
 </ul>
</header>
```